# Get the data element value after clicked in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this type of link:

```
<a href="#" data-module="planning">Planning</a>
```

If I want to detect the click on this type of link, I use:

```
$("a[data-module ='*']").click(function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

But how can I get the `planning` value ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. `a[data-module ='*']` will select `a` tags having  `data-module` attribute value `*`. You should use `a[data-module]` selector which will selects `a` tags having attribute `data-module`.

```js
$('a[data-module]').click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 var module = $(this).attr('data-module');
 alert(module);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside id="app-aside" class="app-aside top light">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="aside-menu-wrapper">
            <div id="aside-top-menu-toggle" class="visible-xs-inline-block">
                <button data-toggle="class" data-target="#aside-top-menu" data-class="open" self-toggle="is-active" class="hamburger hamburger--spin js-hamburger" type="button">
                    <span class="hamburger-box">
                        <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                    </span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <ul class="sf-menu aside-menu aside-top-menu" id="aside-top-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="menu-link" data-module="planning">
                        <span class="menu-text">Planning</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="menu-link">
                        <span class="menu-text">Rooms <i class="zmdi zmdi-caret-down"></i></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" data-module="rooms-list">List rooms</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-module="rooms-create">Create a room</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) API  :

```
$("a[data-module ='*']").click(function() {
    var dataModule = $(this).attr('data-module');
});
```

**EDIT**

Currently your jquery selector is wrong, it is interpreted as :

`Find all <a> tags whose data-module attribute has a value of *`

So in your example, there is no link that matches this condition.

Example: 
I will get all  tags with data-module that  starts with `rooms`. 
Then my valid selector would be  `$('a[data-module^="rooms"]')`

Comment: Hello, could you please told me why it doesn't work here please ?
https://jsfiddle.net/kk6swhaa/

Comment: @PacPac https://jsfiddle.net/kk6swhaa/4/ your selector is wrong, what are you trying to achieve for this one? all href with data-module *?

Comment: @PacPac this is the wrong part `a[data-module ='*']` tell me what are you trying to achieve here :) because for now it is interpreted as `find all a tags with data-module whose value is equal to *`. And the reason why it is not working because there is no <a> tag with data-module value of `*`